# Export to Excel with all used cells bordered and centered

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

I have a table I've created in R and am looking to output it to Excel using `write.xlsx` but with all used cells bordered and centered. Can anyone help please, I gather I need to create a style and then apply that as part of the `write.xlsx` command but am not sure how to do so.

Below code is the current write function which just exports without any formatting.

Thank you!

```
write.xlsx(FinalOutput, "//user017/userslocal/aaaa/Documents/R Experiments/FinalOutput1.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an excel style with:

```
library(openxlsx)
custom_style <- openxlsx::createStyle(...)
```

And apply it to your excel file:

```
wb <- openxlsx::createWorkbook()
openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "S1")
openxlsx::writeData(wb, FinalOutput)
openxlsx::addStyle(wb, S1, custom_style)
openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, "//user017/userslocal/aaaa/Documents/R Experiments/FinalOutput1.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```